# User can login from Android, but he cannot use functions that require authorization (using Django as backaend)

Tags: android, python, django, authentication, authorization

I am using Django build in authenticate functions. The android user is successfully logging in, but he cannot use the functions(Ex. on /events the logged in user needs to get some content, but he does not get it, even though he logged in) Any help ?
- Quick notice. When i log in from web it is working fine( i can use all the functions ).

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere between line 1 and line 99999999. Without any code how should we know what is going on?

Comment: Wwhen you mention Android, you mean browser on Android device or Android app? Because it looks like on Android session cookie is not saved... but in apps, usually some kind of token based auth is used and therefore require speciall handeling in Django.

Comment: Sounds like a session issue. The android device are not persisting a cookie or not sending the right headers. Hard to know what the problem is with so few details. We don't even know if this is a web app or an API for an actual app.. or of this is stateless or session based.

Comment: Its on Android app, trying to log in via my android phone.